# Why does my nginx pod crash when using openshift code ready containers (crc)

Tags: openshift

I installed crc, and immediatly after creating a cluster, i run the following command:

oc new-app nginx

When i check the status of my pods, it says it crashed. If I look into the pod logs, it has access denied errors. Other images have the same result. I even created a node server image, and when node attempts to start, it has access denied errors. It seems there is something i dont understand about the permissions when a pod is managed by a deployment. Any thoughts or help is appreciated.

I tried various images and i tried creating my own with no success.

Comment: Please put your error messages on your question and also need to show file/directory permissions which your pod got error when it accessed.

Comment: Also please provide the versions of what you are using. What version of CRC (since it's not even called CRC anymore) and which version of the NGINX image it is trying to create.